# Setting Up Redis High Availability (HA) on open-shift cluster and virtual machines (VM's)

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, openshift, redis-cluster

I have a spring boot application which is deployed on open-shift cluster. The application uses Redis, so for that I have also deployed redis docker image on open-shift registry.
This redis image is simple one.

I want my redis to be Highly Available.
I have read about redis sentinal but got mostly the theoretical part.
I wanted to know how can I set redis HA on open-shift and connect it to my application as I have done with simple redis.

And also How can I set up redis HA on virtual machines(VM's)

Any Thoughts on this ?

Comment: You can have a look at bitnami charts: [chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/redis/helm) and [github](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis)